# How to dynamically resize iframe height in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, iframe

I created the following function to resize the height of an `iframe` element always to `100%` after load:

```
app.directive('iframeAutoSize', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('load', function() {
                console.log(element[0]);
                var iFrameHeight = element[0].contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
                element.css('height', iFrameHeight);
            });
        }
}}]);
```

usage:

```
<iframe iframe-auto-size src="..." />
```

Problem: I'm getting the following error when launching it:

`Error: Permission denied to access property "document"`.

Obviously it's not allowed to execute `window.document` on the iframe element. But how could I else find out the height?

I'd prefer a plain angular/js solution without jquery.

Comment: only way you can access that iframe is if you control code in both parent and iframe domain

Comment: Ok, so I issume there is no existing solution to embed an external page and resize the component to maximum height?

Comment: if you control the iframe code you can

Comment: @charlietfl yes I control the iframe component, but NOT the content to be loaded inside the iframe,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this isn't a AngularJS Error, this is a [SOP Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy), the iFrame is probably sandboxed!

The iFrame comes from a different domain??

Comment: Yes the content to be embedded into the iframe comes from a different domain. Is it possible to overcome this error?

Comment: You maybe not consider this as error, this is how the SOP works!

You can't do anything with this content because isn't a your content!

Read the link I posted before, but i don't think that you'll find any workaround!

It's security :)